# Getting error while executing Stroredprocedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE javao
  (
    numberw IN number,
    emp_name OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN emp_name FOR SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_no = numberw;
END;
  EXEC javao(1)
```

**Table structure**

```
Name                         Type                                  
-------------                -------- 
EMP_NO                       NUMBER                      
EMP_NAME                    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)    
ADDRESS                      VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)     
PH_NO                         NUMBER(10)
```

While executing above stored procedure am getting error.That error is

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'JAVAO'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

please try to help what is the wrong in my code.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. You've defined your procedure with two formal parameters and unless those parameters do not have default values the number of actual parameters passed  into the procedure should be equal to the number of formal parameters.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnow then `out` parameter which values will pass??/

Comment: You should pass in a variable that is of `ref cursor` data type. See @Alex Poole 's answer.

Comment: ya i got it.then how to call this procedure in `JDBC` program.Please suggest me..

Comment: @NicholasKrasnow  please suggest me

Comment: [Here is a good example](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php) of how to call a PL/SQL stored procedure with ref cursor `out` parameter in java on Tim Hall's website.

Comment: thanq i got it thaq for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nicholas Karasnov says, you need the arguments in the call to match the procedure declaration. In this case you have an `OUT` parameter, so you need somewhere for the data you're selecting to go - something corresponding to the `sys_refcursor` parameter type.

If you're using SQL*Plus to test this you can declare a [SQL*Plus variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm) for this and then pass that as a bind variable, and then use the [`print`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm) command to display the cursor contents:

```
variable rc refcursor
exec javao(1, :rc);
print rc
```

This works in SQL Developer too. When you call the procedure from other code, you'll have a variable declared in a PL/SQL block, or in an external application (e.g. via `jdbc`), but the details of those depend on what you're doing.

To call from Java, you'd do something like:

```
// get connection
CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call javao(?, ?) }");
cStmt.setInt(1, 1);
cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.cursor);
cStmt.execute();
ResultSet rSet = ((OracleCallableStatement) cStmt).getCursor(2);
while (rSet.next())
{
    // get columns from result set row and do something with the data
}
```

... but that's bordering in pseudocode, and you'll need to read the documentation to fill in the blanks (and correct any errors; you probably need Oracle-specific statement types for example), and add object closing and error handling all all that other good stuff.

Comment: your code working perfectly..then how to call these procedure in `JDBC` program..please clearify my doubt

Comment: @user2854207 - that's really a whole new question. You'll need to see how far you can get from the documentation, and if you can't make it work then ask a new question showing what you've done, narrowing it down to a specific problem.

Comment: alex poole i have one doubt on your code can u clarify me please

Comment: why we use `variable rc refcursor`? clarify my doubt

Comment: @user2854207 - that's to declare a ref cursor within SQL*Plus (or Developer), so that you have something to pass as an `OUT` parameter. It is not relevant to calls from Java, only for calling directly from the SQL*Plus command line.

Comment: `create or replace PROCEDURE ADDITION 
(
  A IN NUMBER  
, B IN NUMBER  
, C OUT NUMBER  
) AS 
BEGIN
  C := A+B;
  dbms_output.put_line(c);
END ADDITION;` .how to execute above stored procedure?

Comment: `variable c number
exec ADDITION(2,5, :c);
print c`