# returning result with ref cursor in oracle

Tags: oracle

after creating the procedure, how do i call it. when i will try to execute the procedure, what value shall i put in P2 parameter. or can i call regular way to see the result set through ref cursor? or there are some other arrangement i have to do. would appreciate help

```
create or replace procedure ref_test  
(  
 p1 in table1.col1%type  
,p2 out sys_refcursor  
)  
as  
begin  
open p2 for  
select * from table1  
where col1 = p1;  
end;  
/
```

Comment: Since you mentioned in a comment that you need to call this from Java, [this is related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19421355/266304), and [so is this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21913471/266304). Not sure they count as exact duplicates though. I'm sure there's one out there somewhere. It would have been helpful to give that information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it this way:

```
declare
    vCur sys_REFCURSOR;
    vVar table1%ROWTYPE;
begin
    ref_test(1, vCur);
    loop
        fetch vCur into vVar;
        exit when vCur%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(vVar.col1 || ' - ' || vVar.col2);
    end loop;
end;
```

However I would recommend to explicitly list the fields, instead of using `*`.

Comment: hi aleksej, i am making that procedure for reporting purpose and output of refcursor will be called directly from procedure by java. i can declare anonymous block for testing. any other suggestion?  the sql will be a joining of 5-6 tables